# How to "define remote" in Pycharm?

Tags: python, git, github, pycharm

After getting Pycharm set up and watching some [quick tutorials about connecting it with Github](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tGb9FK6zVM&), I still can't find anywhere that is giving me the full information for how to connect PyCharm to GitHub. I think that I've managed to accomplish most of it, but there is one final step that I still haven't figured out.

[Jetbrain documents how to sync with Github](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/pushing-changes-to-the-upstream-git-push.html), which says to "Click this link and specify the remote name and URL in the dialog that opens." Unfortunately, as a beginner to coding, I have no idea was the remote URL is, and that page doesn't even say what a remote URL is. I can't find any information beyond what is on the [Jetbrains website](http://www.jetbrains.com).

There is [one question on StackOverflow from a few years ago that about setting up a remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754903/cant-set-a-remote-with-pycharm/41585461#41585461), but the answers merely say that "You need to set up a remote" without saying how to do so. So, how do I set up a remote? How do I define remote? What URL should I use, and how to I go about finding it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Pycharm's documentation is pretty lacking, I fear.  If I ever figure it out, I'll post the answer.

Comment: Checkout the answer from a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17888261/11823331

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, by "remote" they mean the location of your repo on Github. You can get this by clicking the green "clone or download" on the repo's Github page.